# launching fragment from dialogfragment vs fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have a `main activity` which hosts 2 `fragments` basically. Each of these `Fragments` have a `ListView` with  a bunch of rows. `OnItemClickListener` on a row opens up a `DialogFragment` with detailed data.

On the `DialogFragment` I have a button and on `DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonOnClickListener` I want to launch another fragment with this detailed data.

1. Is it right to launch `Fragment` from a `DialogFragment`?
2. If not, Should I be launching this `Fragment` from parent fragment after `DialogFragment` has dismissed. (I have 2 fragments in this case and any of them can be the parent)
3. or should I be launching it from `MainActivity`.(But, launching from `MainActivity` might have problems, since I dont launch my `DialogFragment` from `MainActivity` and `MainActivity` doesn't have the data, `ArrayAdapter` of the fragments have the data.

Comment: When you say that you are launching a `Fragment` from a `DialogFragment`, do you mean that the `Fragment` is part of the dialog, or it is another `DialogFragment` being displayed?

Comment: @SimonH, It is not part of the dialog, It's a separate fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Fragment` shares `FragmentManager` with `Activity`, so its ok to launch a new `Fragment` from `DialogFragment` using `getFragmentManager()` method

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all Fragments including `DialogFragment` are recommended to be launched and be managed from `Activity` as `Fragment` inevitably requires a context but the context is only given from `Activity`.

Launching `Fragment` does not require a `context` per se, but I said *inevitably* as we use `getString` or resource dependent codes which requires `context`.

So, in your question, though it is hard to make, **#3** is preferred choice to implement.

In case of the data in `ArrayAdapter`, you can have two options.

1. Re-design your data layer in order to access from any views. Repository pattern or Flux pattern might help to refactor the app.
2. Just implement to **#2** way. It is easiest and efficient way to handle the `DialogFragment`. It is good to manipulate `FragmentManager` as close as possible from `Activity`. If not, `ChildFragmentManager` will make another headache.

**#1** is simplest to go, but inside of tab means that it can be invisible so to be garbage collected.

Comment: I have seen a lot of post talking about, not launching fragment from fragment, but no concrete reasons, also google I/O 2016 seems to be suggesting the opposite, also then why they have child fragments etc. ?

Comment: @user1324887 // The main reason not to manage child fragments from a fragment is because of super-complex Activity-Fragment life cycle as this figure describes; https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle Google I/O is not for _each specific_ requirements and implementation but for practices and demonstrations. When you code more with Android, you might want to make fragment sandwiches thinner and simpler as they will generate lots of crashes and dirty workarounds.

Comment: Definitely agree with making `Fragments` thinner and simpler. However it's straightforward to get context in a `Fragment`
`fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_component_picker, container, false);`  `fragmentView.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a skeleton example of a `DialogFragment` where the dialog contains a `Fragment` and also pops up another `DialogFragment`

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            MyFragmentOnTheDialog.MyFragmentOnTheDialogListener,
            MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment.MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragmentListener
    {
```

For the fragment on the dialog , it is dynamically added.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // fragment dynamically added
        mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        // create a new instance of the fragment. 
        mMyFragmentOnTheDialog= MyFragmentOnTheDialog.newInstance();

        // Add the fragment to the layout by replacing a frame on the layout
        FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_my_fragment, mMyFragmentOnTheDialog);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        }
```

For the popup additional `DialogFragment` MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment ...

```
    btnPick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment frag = MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment.newInstance();
                    // pass to the Dialog Fragment a reference to this container class
                    // in order to set up the interface between this fragment and that fragment.
                    // The reference to the MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment is returned to 'frag'
                    frag.setMyAdditionalPopupDialogFragmentListener(EventAddFragment.this);
                    frag.show(ft, frag.TAG);

        }
    });
```

(You will need to add a setMyAdditionalPopupDialogFragmentListener in your other `DialogFragment` to set up the callback)

```
/**
 * Sets the listener interface with the container class to allow a callback to be made from this
 * fragment. The container class must implement the interface
 * @param listener The container class that has implemented the MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment interface
 * @return A reference to this fragment
 */
public MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragment setMyAdditionalPopupDialogFragmentListener(MyAdditionalPopupDialogFragmentListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    return this;
}
```

re. Youngjae's answer - no issues with `context` here.

Comment: Yes. Of course, bringing up Fragment is not required context per se. I said _inevitably_ as we use `getString` or resource dependent codes which requires `context`. I hardly imagine that codes in Fragment are independent from `context` in application development.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I am also interested in knowing what is the correct/recommended way, rather than knowing how its done. (Could you please point out why it would be the recommended way? ), Also, it's a separate fragment outside the dialog.

Comment: Ok, well my supplementary answer would be that it's horses for courses. I've not read any doctrines from Google saying that "this is the 'correct' way", or "THOUGH SHALT NOT do it THIS way". It is possible and simple to do what you want to do by launching a `Fragment` from a `DialogFragment`. Whether it's what you decide to do is your personal or company policy choice. And apologies for wasting my time providing you with details.

Comment: @SimonH, Apologies if I came off wrong, But, I am thankful for providing the information. Its definitely helpful. In my current scenario, I feel that launching fragment from DialogFragment would be the right thing, But, since there are so many posts and people suggesting against it. I wanted to dig down and see why it would not be a good decision vs, why it would be., other than being a architectural/personal choice.

Comment: No worries (though an upvote might have been nice ;-) I have to say that I've not read a lot decrying calling a fragment class from another fragment class. And I'm still not 100% sure what you mean by "launching a fragment" in your question. A fragment must either be embedded in another activity/fragment layout or else exist in a dialog. So if yours is not in a dialog then where is it?

Comment: @SimonH, I dont get when you say a fragment should be embedded. So far for each fragment I have a java class  and an XML view for each fragment for ex: lets say `UserActionFragment.java` and `fragment_useraction.xml`. In one case I have `RowActionDialogFragment.java` and corresponding `fragment_rowaction.xml`. Now from `RowActionDialogFragment.java` I am trying to start a new fragment called `FullActionFragment.java` with a view `fragment_fullaction`. Also, I tried the solution you suggested. Its not seem to starting the fragment.

Comment: Where does `R.id.frame_my_fragment` come from? The activity or the fragment ?